# How to clone a WebService GitHub repo and make it works on Intellij Idea

Tags: git, tomcat, github, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I have some problem with my web service application. So, I created the project in My Intellij Idea ide, configured Tomcat and it works properly then I created a GitHub repository and committed the project. After a few days I tried on the other laptop to clone the project and I noticed some problems.

- I can't see new Servlet in the menu
- When I run the project the tomcat server works and deploy the project but in the browser, I have 404 error.

I tried to be sure tomcat works, and it works.

I expect to clone the GitHub repo and make it wors. Then I expect to be able to create a new servlet, so to see the "new servlet" in the menu options.

Comment: Did you commit all files including .iml file and .idea folder?

Comment: Yes I commit all file including that

Comment: Is it possible to share project or reproduce the issue with simple one?